# hyper link on watson conversation

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

we pasted this code on watson conversation
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXWFlJa3ZIN09TbHM/view?usp=sharing

The output is weird on facebook messenger, we are able click on that link, but it's not supposed to be there,any advice would be appreciated

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXTzVkV2d1aEtTZFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please take a look at this { "output": { "text": { "values": [ "Please take a look at the following link <a href=\"drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXYTJuc0o2MkkyTk0/‌​…\">click here</a>" ], "selection_policy": "sequential" } } }

Answer (score 0):

Joe, if you use this example without the `http://` or `https://` it understands that it is `localhost` or your domain, and does not redirect, or redirect wrong.

I did your example inside my conversation app, and redirect to `localhost/YourURLinsideHref`

**Try it (works fine to me):**

```
     { "output": 
        { "text": 
           { "values": [ "Please take a look at the following link <a href="http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXYTJuc0o2MkkyTk0/‌​‌​">click here</a>" ], 
             "selection_policy": "sequential" 
           } 
        } 
     }
```

You can add in your normal response inside Conversation Service:

```
<a  target="_blank" href="https://google.com.br">Google</a>.\n<br/><br/>
```

**EDIT:**

> Done a lot of research on this. Facebook doesn't seem to support the
>   usual codes which create hyperlinked text (e.g. "click here") that
>   links the clicker to your specified external website. for now, you can
>   only attach a link in it's full form (e.g. "www.blahblah.com")

[Official information inside facebook forum](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=548602681841129).

Comment: I pasted yours but there's a "x" on watson conversation, I tried the follwoing, still gets no luck...  {
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "please take a look this link: <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">click here</a>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}

Comment: run it on chrome or ie looks fine

Comment: 1. https://4746fe75.ngrok.io/  -> type "link test" ->  it works , but when you test it on facebook messenger , it does not work, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks Sayuri, we'll create a short link instead,

Comment: Can we have an icon instead of a link ? do I have to open a new ticket for this ? Thanks

Comment: New ask, in this case. I'm not sure about that but if I search something about I'll answer your new question

Comment: Thanks Sayuri, I will open a new ticket , hopefully, you can pick it up for me, thanks